# How to create an anonymous type within linq query with TypeScript

Tags: linq, typescript, angular

I am using angular2 with TypeScript.

I have created this Linq query:

```
 var groupedGradingKeyTables = Enumerable.AsEnumerable(gradings)
                .Select(pair => new GradingKeyPair(pair))
                .Select((g, index) =>  new { g, index })
                .GroupBy(g => g.index / 3, index => index)
                .ToArray();
```

How can I create an `anonymous type` without assigning it to a variable just like the `new { g, index }` with TypeScript?

At the moment the code does not build due to the not working anonymous type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var groupedGradingKeyTables = Enumerable.AsEnumerable(gradings)
                .Select(pair => new GradingKeyPair(pair))
                .Select((g, index) =>  ({ g, index })) // With parenteses...
                .GroupBy(g => g.index / 3, index => index)
                .ToArray();
```

Hope that helps! =)